# Scrolling "hang" or "stick" effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for a way to have some content be "sticky" to the scroll effect. When you scroll past it I want the page to stick to the div for a moment. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Google ? Have you heard of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep seeing this question on here! I recommend jQuery Waypoints: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: I was building my own parallax and wanted the big divs to draw in the scroll for a moment (if that makes sense?) I didn't know quite how to phrase it, but this looks like it will work beautifully, thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome! Could you check off my answer if it ends up working for you? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On scroll event, detect the scrollTop value and change the CSS position of the element you want to be sticky.

I think there are a lot of questions on this subject...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrolltop